# Counting events only once if an event happens more than once every X minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that is filled everytime a user starts a session in my app. But I dont want to count their session more than once if they make it within 10 minutes. How can I do it?

Here's an example of what is returned from the table

```
   select
    *
    from table
    limit 100


+----------+--------+---------+----------------+
| event_ID | userid | city_id |   created_at   |
+----------+--------+---------+----------------+
|        1 | a      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:10 |
|        2 | b      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:11 |
|        3 | a      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:14 |
|        4 | a      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:25 |
|        5 | b      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:27 |
|        6 | c      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:30 |
|        7 | c      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:35 |
|        8 | d      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:40 |
|        9 | d      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:49 |
|       10 | c      |       1 | 15/08/19 10:55 |
+----------+--------+---------+----------------+
```

In the end, I would want to count the *unique* event_ids for each user, based on the premise that a unique event_id is defined by the amount of times it happens every 10 minutes

So it should be something like this in the end:

```
+--------+------------------+
| userid | unique_event_ids |
+--------+------------------+
| a      |                2 |
| b      |                2 |
| c      |                2 |
| d      |                1 |
+--------+------------------+
+--------+------------------+
| Total  |                7 |
+--------+------------------+
```

Any suggestion on how to start?

Comment: In your example d should result in 2 as well (40 and 51)

Comment: You're right, I forgot to edit. It's correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` to determine when the previous event was created for the user.  Then some date filtering and aggregation:

```
select userid, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(created_at) over (partition by userid order by created_at) as prev_created_at
      from t
     ) t
where prev_created_at is null or prev_created_at < created_at - interval '10 minute'
group by userid
```

Comment: But what if user 'a' has 4 events?

    |10:30;
    10:35;
    10:41;
    10:42|

I should have 2 unique events, but I guess it would count as only one, right?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMachado . . . This counts it only once.  I notice that you accepted an equivalent answer posted *7 minutes* after this one.  I suppose you have your reasons.

Comment: I mean I can only choose only one and I didn't think people would care about it that much. but you're right, you answered first, have you accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select
  userid,
  sum(case when created_at - interval '10 minute' < prev then 0 else 1 end)
    as unique_events_ids
from (
  select
    *,
    lag(created_at) over(partition by userid order by created_at) as prev
  from t
) x
group by userid
```

Comment: But what if user 'a' has 4 events? |10:30; 10:35; 10:41; 10:42| I should have 2 unique events, but I guess it would count as only one, right? Since the difference between them is never higher than 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, using this logic it would count only once. This logic considers a "new sessions" starts when 10 minutes have passed since the last interaction.